# System.Diagnostics.Process can't start process

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2003

I'm creating a service on VS2010, using .net framework 4.0 Client Profile. The target machine is Windows Server 2003 64 bits. This service move some files and then executes a process with System.Diagnostics.Process. The trouble is that, even if the taskmanager shows a process as starting, the executable never do whats was made for. Example code:

```
        private void imprimir(string nombreImpresora, int copias, string nombreArchivo)
    {
        try
        {
            string copiasSumatra = "1,";
            for (int i = 1; i < copias; i++)
            {
                copiasSumatra += "1,";
            }

            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string comando = String.Format("-print-to \"{0}\" \"{1}\" -print-settings \"{2}odd,fit\" -silent", nombreImpresora, nombreArchivo, copiasSumatra);
            string filename = '"' + Path.Combine(path, "SumatraPDF.exe") + '"';
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = comando;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            lc.writeToLog("Instruction executed. Exit code: " + proc.ExitCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lc.writeToLog(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

If I execute it on my dev machine (windows 8 pro) or in another test server (Windows Server 2003 32 bits) it makes whats expected. If I run it on the WS2003 64 bit server it does nothing.

I've debugged lots of times to see if it produces some error that I'm missing, but nothing happens. The "lc.writeToLog" method prints text to a file. I've used it to log every single line of the execution, but no error is thrown. Using that method I've concluded that it passes the "proc.WaitForExit()" instruction, so I think it's going to do what I've programmed, but nothing happens.

I have runned the same instruction but passing it a user, password and domain and the result was the same. Also tryed to capture standard error and output but it contained nothing.

What could be the trouble?

Comment: Running another process in general gives you very poor diagnostics when something goes wrong.  Especially when you don't check Process.ExitCode either, the only way you *could* see something going wrong.  Not setting StartInfo.WorkingDirectory is also a big mistake, the file could actually be created but you just can't find it back because you don't know what directory to look in.  Avoid .bat files, anything they can do you can do in C# as well.

Comment: I've updated my code to use your sugestions, as you can see. Now it shows the actual code I'm trying to execute (print a pdf with sumatra pdf). The Process exit code was 2.

Comment: That usually means "File not found", a very common error of course.  Short from a non-existing printer or the file just not being there, *nombreArchivo* has to be a full path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server related issue. After deploying the application onto the production server the issue has disapeared.